# How can I update associated models in a django DeleteView

Tags: python, django

I have a couple of models, `Content` and `Hostname`. `Hostname` has a `content_id` associating the models:

```py
class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    message = models.TextField()

class Hostname(models.Model):
    """
    Hostname model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

On the content delete form/view, I have a drop-down selector to specify what content should be assigned to hostnames that are associated with the content being deleted.

Contents:

- Content1
- Content2
- Content3

Hostnames

- Hostname1 (content_id: Content1)
- Hostname2 (content_id: Content2)

Action:

- Delete Content2, user selects Content3 in the drop-down when deleting Content2
- Hostname2 should be updated to be associated with Content3

The template for the `content_confirm_delete` looks like this, when selecting the `content_id`:

```
<select name="content_id">
    {% for new_content in contents %}
        {% if new_content.id != content.id %}
            <option value="{{ new_content.id }}" {% if default_content == new_content.name %}selected{% endif %}>{{ new_content.name }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The content delete is using a `generic.DeleteView`:

```
class ContentsDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Content
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content.list')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thus far gone with this:

```
class ContentsDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Content
    success_url = reverse_lazy('content.list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        default_content_id = Setting.objects.get(name='default-content').value
        Hostname.objects.select_related().filter(content_id=self.object.id).update(content_id=request.POST.get('content_id', default_content_id))
        return super(ContentsDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Seems to be working, but not sure if this is the "right" way according to Django.